# Saving the edited ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, ag-grid, sheetjs

Pretty new to ag-Grid. I have loaded an `xlsx` file into `ag-Grid`. I have set the `editable` property to `true` to allow editing. Now I want to save/export this edited grid. How can I approach this?

Comment: You must have read these by now: [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below ag-grid api "**exportDataAsExcel(params)**" to export the ag-grid as excel.

```
gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(params);
```